# It is possible to use a Shape Drawables for round corners and a 9-patch image for shadows simultaneously?

Tags: android, xml, background, shadow, nine-patch

I have a textview, I want it with a solid color blackground and round corners with border. Thats works fine with this code.

main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="-20dp"
    android:layout_width="210dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_below="@id/coverflowReflect"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@drawable/round_corners"
    >
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="210dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:id="@+id/statusText"
                android:textSize="16sp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

and round_corners.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

  <solid android:color="#0101A1"/>
  <corners android:radius="4dp"/>
  <stroke android:width="2.5dip" android:color="#E27109" />
  <padding android:left="0dp" android:top="0dp" android:right="0dp"         android:bottom="0dp" /> 
   </shape>
```

The problem is when i want to add a drop shadow with a 9-patch image. I'm familiarized with list-items and i can add another Drawable Shape, but this doesn't allow an image, just only colors as background.

So any idea to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item>
      <shape 
        android:shape="rectangle">
            <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="@color/hr_bottom" />
            <solid android:color="#00FF0000" />
            <padding android:bottom="1dp"/>
        </shape>
   </item>

    <item android:drawable="@drawable/decoration2">

   </item>

</layer-list>
```

You can use layerlist like above.

Also refer to this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7269525/android-background-layer-list-and-scalable-bitmap-item)